# Do I have to store iOS app data on a remote server if I'm implementing Firebase authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, realm

Basically I have a relatively simple iOS gym app that I'm working on. It records things like Dates, exercise names, sets, reps and I'm currently using Realm to persist the data locally. I would like to also implement Firebase authentication, so I would like to know if it's possible to implement User authentication if I'm storing data locally or does it only work if I'm using cloud/real-time storage? If someone could explain this to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I'm relatively new to programming and iOS development so I'm still figuring these things out.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Question: If you are storing the data locally, why would you need multi-user remote authentication services? e.g. if your data is only stored on the device, there would be no need to an authentication server since none of your data is in the cloud. Also, Realm offers basic user authentication. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson answered my question already. Thanks.

Comment: My comment wasn't an answer - just a followup question to help clarify the question so it will be useful to other readers. Why authentication is needed for an app that is local only may need clarification. Just don't want you spending a lot of unnecessary time working through authentication if its not needed - and vice versa - spending a lot of time on Realm if Firebase is a better fit for your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't require you to store any data anywhere, other than what it collects about the user from the authentication provider you're using to sign in the user.  You can do whatever you want with other data.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.